# Double pointers element access using 2-dimension array syntax in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, pointers, syntax, double-pointer

I am new to objective-c and am doing something that works for the moment but am afraid might break someday.

In one of my object, I declare a matrix of integer as instance variable. As I do not know the size of the matrix yet, I declared it like this:

```
int **_matrix;
```

Later in the code, when I know the amount of lines and columns of my matrix, I initialize it like this:

```
_matrix = malloc(sizeof(*_matrix) * columns * lines);
for (i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    _matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * lines);
    for(j = 0; j < lines; j++)
        _matrix[i][j] = -1;
}
```

Assuming my allocation is correct (please, feel free to tell me if it is in fact wrong), can I confidently access the elements using the 2-dimension array syntax?

I am asking because from what I read, when you create an actual 2-dimension array the memory is reserved continuously but that it might not be the case using double pointers.
Therefore I am afraid that calling

```
_matrix[i][j]
```

would actually point to a random place in the memory (and not the place I allocated).

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: you may want to use `calloc` to get a zero-filled avoid getting a matrix full of uninitialized data after allocation... but depends on your usage and how large your allocations are.

Comment: Thank you for the tips nielsbot. Actually, as I want my matrix to be initialized with -1 and not 0, it is better to use malloc. Performance-wise this save a "round" of initialization.

Comment: @RenaudC.: FYI, not really relevant to the question, but if we're suggesting improvements, a simpler and probably slightly faster way to do this would be `memset(_matrix[i], -1, lines)` instead of the inner loop.

Comment: another side note: calloc can be faster than you might expect, since it can take advantage of some kernel/VM tricks to provide zero-filled pages... but probably only matters for some usages and larger allocations.

Comment: @RenaudC. yes, if I had read your code more carefully I would have seen the -1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. It is true that two-dimensional arrays on the stack are generally allocated contiguously, but you needn't worry about that. The important thing is that the brackets are evaluated one pair at a time, not as some special `[][]` operator, and brackets dereference pointers. So it will dereference your first pointer, and then it will dereference the "row" pointer that was yielded by the first dereference.

More info: Array accesses and pointer dereferences are equivalent. The expression `x[y]` is equivalent to `*(x+y)`. So your code first dereferences the pointer value `(matrix + i)`, which gives you another pointer value (since you had an array of pointers). After this, your code dereferences the pointer `(matrix[i] + j)` and assigns it the value -1. As you can see, this is precisely what you want it to do.